# mui datagrid with React-dnd

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, react-dnd

I used to have a mui treeview which is simple to extend with react-dnd because treeitem is a react component.

In a datagrid however, the row are an array of JSON object and not a react component anymore.
Is there any way for me to update the "sub-component" within the datagrid to enhance it with dragndrop ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override default components using `components props`.
Like this:

```js
<DataGrid
    apiRef={apiRef}
    columns={cols}
    rows={rows}
    treeData={typeof treeKey !== "undefined"}
    getTreeDataPath={(row: any) => row[treeKey]}
    groupingColDef={groupingColDef}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
    pagination={true}
    disableColumnFilter
    experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
    autoHeight
    editMode="row"
    rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
    onRowModesModelChange={(newModel) => setRowModesModel(newModel)}
    onCellDoubleClick={handleCellDoubleClick}
    onRowEditStart={handleRowEditStart}
    onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
    processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
    initialState={{
        pagination: {
            pageSize: 10
        }
    }}
    components={{
        Toolbar,
        NoRowsOverlay,
        Row: DndRow     // this is it in your case
    }}
    componentsProps={{
        toolbar: {
            selectedCellParams,
            richToolbar
        },
        cell: {
            onFocus: handleCellFocus
        },
        row: {
            onContextMenu: handleContextMenu,
            style: { cursor: "context-menu" }
        }
    }}
/>
```